# Notication bars like Facebook

Tags: facebook, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for something like the notification bar of Facebook; the ones which say how many "friend requests", "Notification" or "Messages" you have. Is there anything fancy implemented with bootstrap, foundation or... that we can use? or I need to use CSS and.. to create my own?

Thanks

Comment: sorry if I didn't ask correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap does actually already have the concept built in, it calls them badges:

- http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges

Seems like somebody has has the idea before but its for a library called CakePHP and I can't see any easy way to pull the information out:

- https://github.com/beeman/cakephp-bootstrap-notifications/blob/master/README.md

I found a nice example snippet here, but the notification badge is on the left rather then in the top right:

- http://jsfiddle.net/WBTf8/1/

Which has markup like this:

```
<div class="navbar" style="position: static;">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
              <a href="#" 
                 data-html="true"
                 data-placement="bottom"
                 data-toggle="popover"
                 data-content="Notification 1<br/>Notification 2"
                 data-original-title="Notifications">
                  <span class="badge badge-success">2</span> Notifications
              </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
</div>
```

And a startup function like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
})
```

It uses a popover to show the notifications. You are still going to have to write more code to turn it into a feature though like being able to push the notifications to the client while the page is loaded, mark them as processed when the user opens the notification menu, and pass that info back to the data store.